# Can a Highcharts range selector use non-date linear ranges?

Tags: highcharts

I am using the HighStock JS lib to produce a chart that uses a linear series (not a time-series) for the xAxis.

I'd still like to use the range-selector in order to zoom to pre-determined ranges within my linear series. Is this possible?

For example; say my xAxis has a series:

`[[121,616],[122,600],[123,605],[124,585.5],[125,575.5],[126,580.5],[127,582],[128,582],[129,584],[130,583]]`

I'd like to use the range selector to zoom to the last `n` in the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is supported out of the box. But what is supported is [Axis.setExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes%28%29)

You can dynamically set the zoom of the xAxis using this method, and hence you can create your very own range selector for non timeseries charts

[Axis.setExtremes() How to @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/members/axis-setextremes/)

[My attempt at custom range selectors @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/cdAgr/)